# Spring @Transactional with base and subclasses

Tags: java, spring, transactions, spring-transactions

I am confused about `@Transactional` annotation with base and subclasses. I have the following code with several generic subclasses derived from the base class `CustomRepository<T>` which implements `ICustomRepository<T>`. I want all the methods of the interface `ICustomRepository<T>` be transactional.

```
// class ActivityCustomRepository.java
@Repository
public class ActivityCustomRepository extends CustomRepository<Activity> {
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "activity";
public ActivityCustomRepositoryImpl(ActivityRowMapperImpl rowMapper, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    super(TABLE_NAME, rowMapper, jdbcTemplate);
}

// class PersonCustomRepository.java
@Repository
public class PersonCustomRepository extends CustomRepository<Person> {
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "person";
public PersonCustomRepository(PersonRowMapperImpl rowMapper, JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
    super(TABLE_NAME, rowMapper, jdbcTemplate);
}   

// CustomRepository.java
@Transactional
public class CustomRepository<T> implements ICustomRepository<T> {
    private final String tableName;
    private final RowMapper<T> rowMapper;
    private final JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;
    @Override
    public List<T> findAll() {
        return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate("... ", rowMapper);
    }
}

// ICustomRepository.java
public interface ICustomRepository<T> {
     List<T> findAll();
}
```

Is it enough to put `@Transactional` just in the base class so that the call `findAll()` from sublasses also become transactional. Or it is better to place `@Transactional` on subclasses and not put it on base class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have investigated it.
As `@Transactional` is an inhereted annotation then if we mark a base class by `@Transactional` then all its subclasses will be also `@Transactional` automatically.

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE, ElementType.METHOD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Inherited
@Documented
public @interface Transactional {
...
}
```

The inhereted annotation [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/annotation/Inherited.html):

> Indicates that an annotation type is automatically inherited. If an
> Inherited meta-annotation is present on an annotation type
> declaration, and the user queries the annotation type on a class
> declaration, and the class declaration has no annotation for this
> type, then the class's superclass will automatically be queried for
> the annotation type. This process will be repeated until an annotation
> for this type is found, or the top of the class hierarchy (Object) is
> reached. If no superclass has an annotation for this type, then the
> query will indicate that the class in question has no such annotation.
> Note that this meta-annotation type has no effect if the annotated
> type is used to annotate anything other than a class.
>
> Note also that
> this meta-annotation only causes annotations to be inherited from
> superclasses; annotations on implemented interfaces have no effect.